# Electron - How to change the default .icns that Electron adds

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, electron

I'm using versions `"electron-prebuilt": "^0.36.4"` and "`"electron-packager": "^5.2.1"`.

I package my `.app` by adding this `script` in my `package.json` file:

`"package-mac": "electron-packager . tE --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --version=0.36.4"`

On the terminal, I type `npm run-script package-mac`.

The `tE.app` is inside a generated folder (in the root of my project) named `tE-darwin-x64`. See the picture below:

[image: My Electron App]

Comparing to other tutorials around the web, there are typically more folders and files generated by `electron-packager`. And they seem to be missing in mine. Particularly, the `info.plist` file is missing. I think I'm missing some miles because I want to change the default `.icns` to my custom one, and I think I need the `info.plist`. Though I'm not sure.

What am I doing doing wrong and how to I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `electron-packager` anyway, look into using the `--icon` option ([see here](https://github.com/maxogden/electron-packager#programmatic-api)).

If you want to do it manually, look into the contents of your tE.app: open it in the Terminal, it's just a folder, or right-click in Finder and open package contents -- that's were you will find the contents you're missing.

Comment: How do I manually change the `atom.icns`? Is there a command to add in my package script inside `package.json`

Comment: I figured it out. I just add `--icon=newIcon.icns` in my package script in `package.json` file. Thanks!